# Is it better to have second-level or third-level ccTLD in terms of SEO?

Tags: domains, top-level-domains, local-seo, cctld

For example: `example.co.pk` OR `example.pk`

My instinct inclines me towards `.pk` ccTLD because of its shortness and easy memorability. Not sure if later on it might hurt my rankings and traffic on the website. My clients are mostly local!

Which one is better for SEO? In case I seek to attract international clients in the region surrounding Pakistan such as Middle East or South East Asia, which one of these domains will allow more visibility in their respective local SERPs?

Comment: As weird as @Goyllo's answer is, it is true.  I just read it on Google support page. However, I just used a VPN to check my .nz site and it **is** indexed from USA.  So, it probably does not matter.  But if you are worried, then I would suggest getting a non-country domain as well, and make that the main domain.  Then redirect from .pk ones to the main domain.

Comment: @RohitGupta In my experience, using a country-specific domain doesn't mean Google will exclude your site from search results in other countries, but it does mean that they see your site as being less relevant to people searching outside your own country, and that will affect your ranking. It often results in much lower ranking than in your own country (depending on how competitive the search term is). Using a non-specific domain as you suggest is better to target multiple locations... unfortunately it can be very difficult to get a suitable .com or other popular TLDs these days :)

Comment: On Yandex, you can actually specify your target market.  In fact they pester you until you do.  It's stupid relying on TLDs to know what country someone is from.  I don;t think it is that hard to find suitable domains, there are so many new one TLDs around, such as online, software, app.

Answer (score 1):

Both will target the same country automatically, it means you can't change the location in your search console, once you choose .pk or .co.pk[, Google will consider you're targeting only pakistani visitors](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/62399?hl=en). So it is your choice to pick only one. There is no any SEO benefits or disadvantages.

I will suggest first understand your audience, and then choose which you should pick up. I know Google are using .co.pk for pakistan and Google.co.in for India, but most of website like amazon now use `.in` for indian user, and most of other local eCommerce site also prefer to use `.in` **because it is short and easy to remember**. So first know your local audience and then understand what they prefer most? `.co.pk` or `.pk` only.

For me now a days most of Indian website use `.in` for their local website, only few of them go with `.co.in`, but in general Google will treat them same, so choose wisely :)